# Need to upgrade Windows Server 2012 evaluation to Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, upgrade

I mistakenly installed Windows Server 2012 Evaluation instead of Windows Server 2012 R2 Evaluation. Now my client just bought the license key for 2012 R2, and I am not sure how to proceed. Is it possible to insert the retail CD that has the key, and perform an upgrade from Server 2012 Evaluation to Server 2012 R2 Retail? [This article explains that although it could be possible, it is not correct](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/tips-for-an-easy-upgrade-from-windows-server-2012-to-windows-server-2012-r2/).

Anybody have any experience with this? It would be very preferable to not have to perform a complete reinstall.

Comment: It's possible to do (see my answer), but without more details about what the specific problem you're having is, it's not going to be possible to give a specific answer... so what's the problem you have when you try to upgrade?

Comment: 1. Don't take advice from people who say something is "not correct" without explaining **why**. I know what the article is talking about, but they should be *ashamed* of their vagueness, and it does **not** apply to your situation. 2. The eval and standard retail versions are the same (other versions are *slightly* different). The new ISO does not have a key in it. They provide the license key separately. Use either a retail or evaluation ISO to upgrade, then install the new license key. 3. Get a mentor, someone who really knows their stuff, to bounce softballs off, like this question.

Comment: @Chris S Oh yes, the license key is separate, I meant to say the DVD castle license key on it, not embedded in the install media itself. So should I go ahead and perform the upgrade process from the DVD?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do what you want.  [Microsoft has a page on the topic here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn303416.aspx) listing what versions of prior OSes can be upgraded to which versions of Server 2012 R2.

Comment: I don't see the conversion path for Server 2012 Evaluation to Server 2012 R2 Standard though. Should I go ahead and perform the upgrade without fear of having to do a reinstall?

Comment: @Carlo71 Yes - if it's not upgradable, it will error out, so there's little reason not to try.  Make sure you have current backups, but that's always good advice.

Comment: Ok good. Yes I do have snapshots of the VM, so I'll give it a try!